# Most appropriate thing to do with Main() method for long running async processes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a basic C# console application that executes a fairly long running process involving timers and asynchronous requests.  The sole purpose of the Main() method is to initialize the timers and then let them do their thing for the next few hours.

I know that Windows Services are appropriate for many long running processes, but doesn't feel appropriate for this use case (executed manually when needed, always terminated within a day, no hurdles of having to install the Service, etc).

Right now, I simply do:

```
while (true)
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

Throwing in a Thread.Sleep seems ... dirty for some reason.  Or is that really the best thing to do to stop the application from terminating before the async process are complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one/multiple [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to communicate from the background threads to the foreground thread.

The foreground thread in `Main` could wait until all background threads signaled that they are finished.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be Thread.Sleep, but isntead you should be waiting on some sort of event that would get signaled when there is *anything* to do, including shuting yourself down.

The application you describe though would much better fit as a service, not as a console app.

Comment: But a Service is so heavy for something that just needs to be run manually and has to be tweaked every single time.  But obviously Service implements some logic similr to what I am looking for - so what does the ServiceBase abstraction do?

Comment: ServiceBase would handle the waiting for you. But the primary reason is that if your app does nothing but sits idle for *hours* at end, it runs the risk of being closed when the user session terminates. Running as a service would keep the app alive between user logoff/logon events and allow it to do it's work, whatever that is.